While-you-type spell checking not (always) working in Safari (and others?)
For the last few versions of Safari, and lots of other programs now that I think about it, on-the-fly spell checking with the red underline is not working. Automatic replacement does work, and I can see a red underline in this editor (amusingly, on the word "Safari" because of the comma I think), but I am not seeing it in other editors like the Wiki. For instance, I have selected a term that is spelled incorrectly, yet there is no red underline (and no, unselecting it doesn't make it appear):

I went to check the option in the menu, and found this:

Can anyone offer a reason why this is greyed out?
